# What are the disadvantages of React.js memo function?

Tags: reactjs

The memo function of React.js seems to me to have no disadvantages. It seems that the rendering load can be minimized because it is not affected by the state modification of the parent object, but if there is no downside, why is it not the default value for the React.js component?

```js
import { memo } from 'react';

const App: FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return (<div>...</div>);
};

export default memo(App);
```

Comment: It's an extra step React takes to ensure props are the same (but only shallowly). If you don't need it, don't use it. [This is probably worth the read if you're considering it](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/)

Comment: There are definitely downsides: usage of `React.memo()` most definitely incurs extra overhead, space, and memory. Therefore, it is only advisable to use `memo()` when the gains outweigh these costs, which is often when your component renders frequently with the same props. If your component needs to update frequently with DIFFRENT props each time, or if it does not update frequently at all, `memo()` is definitely unnecessary